# Symfony2 WebProfiler (500): Variable "app" does not exist in @Doctrine/Collector/db.html.twig at line 1

Tags: php, symfony, twig, profiler

It's actually the first time for very long that I haven't found a single search result for an error message. On every page load I get a popup message saying:

"An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (500: Internal Server Error).
Do you want to open the profiler?" And when I open the profiler / logs:

```
Variable "app" does not exist in @Doctrine/Collector/db.html.twig at line 1
```

I made some translations and edits of twig templates - really nothing fancy. Now the profiler fails to load on every page.

my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.4.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.*@dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "doctrine/migrations": "1.0.*@dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "~1.0"
},
```

caches cleared, etc. I'm not asking for a solution but do you have any clue what the case could be here?

Thank you very much for your help & time!

Moritz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may still be related to the cache, try to rebuild your bootstrap cache in addition to cache:clear prod & dev.

```
 php ./vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

PS: the path may be different in your symfony version.

Comment: yup, I tried that too. Sadly it didn't have any effect :-(

Finally, I just reinstalled the whole vendor directory and somehow that solved the problem. Thank you for your time, @Nawfal !